# Contabilizar registros de um dataframe

Tags: python, lista, pandas, dataframe

Estou tratando um arquivo de LOG de conexões WIFI. Serão analisados os dados por intervalo de tempo de 15 em 15 minutos e agrupados as conexões dos usuarios por local de conexão dentro do intervalo de tempo. O local que tiver mais conexões do mesmo usuario no mesmo intervalo de tempo, será contabilizado.

Exemplo do Dataframe.
[Imagem do Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvLhY.jpg)

Utilizei o seguinte codigo para testar se o usuario esta dentro do intervalo de tempo:

```
horarios = {
    'intervalo': {
        1: (time(7, 0), time(7, 15)), # intervalo 1, das 07:00h às 07:15h
        2: (time(7, 15), time(7, 30)), # intervalo 2, das 07:15h às 07:30h
        3: (time(7, 30), time(7, 45)), # intervalo 3, das 07:30h às 07:45h
        4: (time(7, 45), time(8, 0)), # intervalo 4, das 07:45h às 08:00h
        5: (time(8, 0), time(8, 15)), # intervalo 1, das 08:00h às 08:15h
        6: (time(8, 15), time(8, 30)), # intervalo 2, das 08:15h às 08:30h
        7: (time(8, 30), time(8, 45)), # intervalo 3, das 08:30h às 08:45h
        8: (time(8, 45), time(9, 0)), # intervalo 4, das 08:45h às 09:00h
    }
}
encontrado = False
for nome, intervalo in horarios.items(): # para cada intervalo
        i=1
        lista=[]
        while i < 9: #Dentro do intervalo de 1 hora temos 4 opções de 15 em 15 minutos
            y=0
            inicio, fim = intervalo[i] 
            while y < 15: #sera preciso fazer um count no numero de linhas do dataframe para ser a condição de parada
                registro2 = df_registro['Event-Timestamp'].dt.time[y]
                if inicio <= registro2 < fim: # verifica se horário está entre o início e fim do intervalo
                    print(df_registro['User-Name'][y], "-",df_registro['NAS-Identifier'][y])
                    print(f'O registro esta dentro do intervalo {inicio:%H:%M} às {fim:%H:%M}')
                    print("--------------")
                    #Cria uma lista com os dados de Usuario, Local e Hora
                    lista.append([df_registro['User-Name'][y],df_registro['NAS-Identifier'][y],df_registro['Event-Timestamp'].dt.time[y]])
                    encontrado = True
                y += 1
            i += 1
if not encontrado:
    print('Registro fora do intervalo definido')
```

---

### SAIDA:

```
Thiago - Cantina
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Ana - Cantina
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Ana - Cantina
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Ana - DEX
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Jose - DCC
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Thiago - Cantina
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Thiago - Cantina
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Thiago - Cantina
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Ana - DEX
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Thiago - Cantina
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Thiago - DEX
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Thiago - DEX
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Thiago - DCC
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Ana - DEX
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:00 às 08:15

Thiago - DCC
O registro esta dentro do intervalo 08:15 às 08:30
```

Agora preciso contar os usuários por local de conexão dentro do intervalo de tempo.
Utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
df_registro3 = pd.DataFrame(lista,columns=['Nome', 'Local', 'Hora'])
df4 = df_registro3.groupby(['Nome','Local']).count(
print(df4)
```

---

### Saida:

```
Nome   Local
Ana    Cantina     2
       DEX         3
Jose   DCC         1
Thiago Cantina     5
       DCC         2
       DEX         2
```

Nessa saída esta o erro do código. No usuário Thiago o local DCC não poderia ser considerado duas vezes, porque um dos registros está em outro intervalo de tempo. A conexão foi as 08:18, então deveria estar no intervalo 08:15 as 08:30.
O problema esta na criação da lista. Tentei incrementar o nome da lista para que cada intervalo fosse um nome diferente da lista mais não deu certo.

Answer (score -1):

O problema está na utilizacao de `df.groupby`.

Desta maneira voce está apenas agrupando por nome e por local, e para as colunas restantes executando uma contagem (sem filtros ou critérios).

Para atingir seu objetivo voce precisa escolher a coluna para a qual pretende aplicar uma funcao e em seguida definir os "bins" ou grupos que pretende usar. Aqui a minha solucao:
1- Criei grupos para as datas completas em intervalos de 15 Min ( tal como o seu dicionário horários)

```
df['Bins'] = df.Timestamp.dt.floor('15min')
df['Bins'] = df.Timestamp.dt.floor('15min').dt.time  # caso os dias nao sejam relavantes
```

2- Utilizacao correta de `df.groupby`

```
df.groupby(['Nome','Local'])['Bins'].value_counts(sort=False)
```

Como voce pode ver, agrupei em duas colunas e na coluna que me interessa, apliquei a funcao `value_counts()`. Usei sort=False para que o resultado esteja na ordem de cronológica, caso contrário sera ordenado do maior para o menor.

Aqui o meu código:
*df criado das informacoes fornecidas, no entanto usei o perído de 5 Minutos, ao invés de 15 e inseri um novo dia também*, favor disponibilizar algo semelhante da próxima vez abrir uma pergunta.

**Criando o DF com base na imagem fornecida**:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
user =  ['Thiago','Ana','Ana','Ana','Jose','Thiago','Thiago','Thiago','Ana']
local = ['Cantina','Cantina','Cantina','DEX','DCC','Cantina','Cantina','Cantina','DEX']
length= len(user)
date = ['2021-06-05 08:01:0','2021-06-05 08:01:0','2021-06-05 08:03:0','2021-06-05 08:04:0','2021-06-05 08:05:0','2021-06-05 08:06:0','2021-06-05 08:09:0','2021-06-05 08:10:0','2021-07-05 08:11:0']
df=pd.DataFrame({'Nome' : user, 'Local' : local , 'Timestamp' : date})
df['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #  # como usei texto, precisei da conversao para datetime
```

**Criacao dos bins (períodos de 5 Minutos considerando o dia):**

```
df['Bins'] = df.Timestamp.dt.floor('5min')
```

Aqui o DF:

|  | Nome | Local | Timestamp | Bins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Thiago | Cantina | 2021-06-05 08:01:00 | 2021-06-05 08:00:00 |
| 1 | Ana | Cantina | 2021-06-05 08:01:00 | 2021-06-05 08:00:00 |
| 2 | Ana | Cantina | 2021-06-05 08:03:00 | 2021-06-05 08:00:00 |
| 3 | Ana | DEX | 2021-06-05 08:04:00 | 2021-06-05 08:00:00 |
| 4 | Jose | DCC | 2021-06-05 08:05:00 | 2021-06-05 08:05:00 |
| 5 | Thiago | Cantina | 2021-06-05 08:06:00 | 2021-06-05 08:05:00 |
| 6 | Thiago | Cantina | 2021-06-05 08:09:00 | 2021-06-05 08:05:00 |
| 7 | Thiago | Cantina | 2021-06-05 08:10:00 | 2021-06-05 08:10:00 |
| 8 | Ana | DEX | 2021-07-05 08:11:00 | 2021-07-05 08:10:00 |

Aplicacao do `df.groupby` conforme informado acima:

```
df.groupby(['Nome','Local'])['Bins'].value_counts(sort=False)
```

Resultado:

```html
Nome    Local    Bins               
Ana     Cantina  2021-06-05 08:00:00    2
        DEX      2021-06-05 08:00:00    1
                 2021-07-05 08:10:00    1
Jose    DCC      2021-06-05 08:05:00    1
Thiago  Cantina  2021-06-05 08:00:00    1
                 2021-06-05 08:05:00    2
                 2021-06-05 08:10:00    1
Name: Bins, dtype: int64
```