# Listas dentro de estrutura de repetição

Tags: python, lista, while

Preciso gravar os dados da estrutura de repetição em listas com nomes diferentes. O nome da lista precisa ser baseadas na variável i.
Tenho os seguintes dados de entrada:

| Nome | Local | Hora |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Thiago | Cantina | 08:01 |
| Ana | Cantina | 08:05 |
| Jose | Sala01 | 09:03 |
| Thiago | Sala01 | 09:30 |
| Pedro | Sala01 | 09:45 |
| Ana | Biblioteca | 11:07 |

Código:

```
i=1
lista=[]
    while i <= 4:#repeticacao1
        y=0
        inicio, fim = intervalo[i] #intervalo é um dicionario com periodo de tempos de 1 em 1 hora
        #Os dados do bloco abaixo devem ser gravados em uma lista com o nome list1. Após sair do While(#repeticacao2) e o i for incrementado os dados devem ser gravados em uma lista com o nome list2 e assim por diante.
        while y < 6: #repeticacao2 - A condicação de parada é <6 devido ao numero de registros de entrada
            registro2 = df_registro['Hora'].dt.time[y]
            if inicio <= registro2 < fim: # verifica se horário está entre o início e fim do intervalo
                print(f'O registro esta dentro do intervalo {inicio:%H:%M} às {fim:%H:%M}')
                #Cria uma lista com os dados de Nome e Local
                lista.append([df_registro['Nome'][y],df_registro['Local'][y]])
            y += 1
        i += 1
```

Resultado:

```
[['Thiago', 'Cantina'], ['Ana', 'Cantina'], ['Jose', 'Sala01'], ['Thiago', 'Sala01'], ['Pedro', 'Sala01'], ['Ana', 'Biblioteca']]
```

O resultado é uma lista com todos os registros. Porém dessa forma, esta sendo misturado os intervalos de tempo.

O resultado esperado seria por intervalos de tempo separados. Dessa forma:

```
list1 = [['Thiago', 'Cantina'], ['Ana', 'Cantina']]

list2 = [['Jose', 'Sala01'], ['Thiago', 'Sala01'], ['Pedro', 'Sala01']]

list3 = []

list4 = ['Ana', 'Biblioteca']
```

Tentei criar a lista com `lista[i]` e depois em `lista[i].append` mas não da certo. Como poderia ser feito?

Answer (score -1):

Assim como na resposta anterior, nao está sendo definido um critério para agrupar por horários.

Eu usei a resposta da pergunta anterior : [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/563853/contabilizar-registros-de-um-dataframe)

Inicialmente aglutinei as informacoes dos usuários com o local e uma nova coluna:

```
df['info']=df['Nome'] +' - ' +  df['Local']
```

Em seguida, usando o mesmo critério da resposta anterior, mas desta vez criando um novo DF e agrupando por Bins (intervalos), apliquei uma funcao lambda, para me retornar as entradas unicas dentro deste intervalo:

```
test_df=df.groupby(['Bins'])['info'].apply(lambda x : list(pd.unique(x)))

Bins
2021-06-05 08:00:00    [Thiago - Cantina, Ana - Cantina, Ana - DEX]
2021-06-05 08:05:00                  [Jose - DCC, Thiago - Cantina]
2021-06-05 08:10:00                              [Thiago - Cantina]
2021-07-05 08:10:00                                     [Ana - DEX]
Name: info, dtype: object
```

Agora com este DF utilizei um `for-loop` como voce, mas usei a funcao `globals()` para poder criar variáveis que tenham indices variáveis : lista[i]

```
for i in range(len(test_df)):
    globals()['lista_{}'.format(i)] = test_df[i]
    print('lista_{}'.format(i))
```

Assim cada linha agrupada tornou-se uma lista.